# paypal Adaptive Payment from my custom webservice for an mobile application

Tags: php, web-services, paypal

Can i perform adaptive payment without going to the paypal site.I also can not use the implicit payment as i have to make a paypal chained payment from server site(i.e. webservice) for an ios application.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Adaptive Payments with an iframe or pop-up as oppose to the full redirect if you want.  They call it "Embedded Payments" and you can get more details about it here:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Answer (score 0):

I've found that some mobile devices block the popup with the Lightbox embedded flow.  I now use the mini browser experience for mobile web.

More information regarding the mini browser experience (expType=mini) can be found here:

[Adaptive Payments without modal box or popups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283272/adaptive-payments-without-modal-box-or-popups/17729106)